# Counting number of born males and females by year using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Using pivot, count the number of males and females born by year.

My table is looking the following way:

> name, date_of_birth, gender (M or F)

This is what my code looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        year(p.date_of_birth),p.gender
    FROM 
        person p
) k
PIVOT(
    COUNT(gender) 
    FOR gender IN (
        [M], 
        [F])
) AS pivot_table;
```

However, the YEAR() conversion isn't working. As soon as I delete the YEAR() part, my code is working, however it's then grouping by date, not by year. How do I make it work so that it would group by year?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer won't be the same.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `p.date_of_birth` is a `date` or `datetime`, you were missing a column name for year()

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT  BirthYear = year(p.date_of_birth)
           ,p.gender
           ,value = 1
     FROM  person p
) k
PIVOT(
    sum(value) 
    FOR gender IN (
        [M], 
        [F])
) AS pivot_table;
```

Comment: @Avenger543 Always is.  Happy to help.